# Generating Functions and Equivalent Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions, bessel-functions, stirling-numbers

**Source**: Somewhere in the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/) the below was quoted without proof or reference (I forgot the exact location sorry)

> Prove that for $|q|<1$,
> $$\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac{q^{m(m+1)/2}}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots (1-q^m)}=\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty q^m(1+q)\cdots(1+q^{m-1}).$$

**Attempt**: It is easy to see, denoting $S(n,m)$ as Stirling numbers of the second kind, that

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty S(n,m)q^n=\frac{1}{(1-q)\cdots(1-q^m)},$$

so

$$\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac{q^{m(m+1)/2}}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots (1-q^m)}=\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty S(n,m)q^nq^{m(m+1)/2}.$$

Moreover, we have

$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^\infty (1+q^i) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1-q^{2i}}{1-q^i}=\prod\limits_{\text{odd } i} \frac{1}{1-q^i}=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty S(n,m)q^n$$

which maybe helps us manipulate the RHS but I got stumped here.

**Question**: Any help for proving the identity would be very much appreciated! Bonus points if it is somewhat in the neighborhood of my very imcomplete thought process.

Comment: What do you mean by $q^n|q^m|q^{m/2}?$ Because I can't see how you lost $(m^2+m)/2=m(m+1)/2.$

Comment: I would write the summand on the left side as:$$\prod_{k=1}^{m}\frac{x^k}{1-x^k}$$ which is the generating function $\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(m,i)x^i$ where $f(m,i)$ is the number of ways two write $i$ as $\sum_{k=1}^m kj_k$ where $j_1,\dots,j_m$ are positive integers.

Comment: So the coefficient to $q^i$ in the sum on the left side is the number of tuples $(j_1,\dots,j_n)$ of positive integer such that $\sum_k j_k=i.$

Comment: On the right side, the summand at $q^i$ counts the number of ways to write $i$ as a sum of distinct positive integers, with the maximum term $m.$ So the total coefficient on the right side counts the number of ways to write $i$ as a non-empty sum of distinct positive integers. Now we just need to find a bijection between these sets.

Comment: Add $1$ to both sides (to represent the empty partition), and notice that $q^m(1+q)\dots(1+q^{m-1})=(1+q)\dots(1+q^m)-(1+q)\dots(1+q^{m-1})$. That means we can rewrite this identity as $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \prod_{j=1}^{m}\frac{q^{j}}{1-q^j}=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1+q^m).$$ The generating function on the right counts all partitions with distinct sizes. The one on the left counts their transposes, i.e. partitions whose part sizes form a set $[m]=\{1,\dots,m\}$ for some $m\ge 0$ (and $[0]=\varnothing$).

Comment: Your connection with the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) is not correct. Please double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show the following is valid for $|q|<1$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{q^{m(m+1)/2}}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots (1-q^m)}=\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty q^m(1+q)\cdots(1+q^{m-1})}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> At first we transform the right-hand sum of (1) conveniently. We add $1$ to the right-hand sum and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{1+}&\color{blue}{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}q^m\left(1+q\right)\cdots\left(1+q^{m-1}\right)}\\
> &=1+q+\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}q^m\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}\left(1+q^j\right)\\
> &=1+q+\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\left(\left(1+q^m\right)-1\right)\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}\left(1+q^j\right)\\
> &=1+q+\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\left(\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left(1+q^j\right)
> -\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}\left(1+q^j\right)\right)\\
> &=1+q+\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{m=2}^{M}\left(\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left(1+q^j\right)
> -\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}\left(1+q^j\right)\right)\\
> &=1+q+\lim_{M\to\infty}\left(\prod_{j=1}^{M}\left(1+q^j\right)
> -(1+q)\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(1+q^j\right)}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Using (2) we can now write the assumed identity (1) as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{1+\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{q^{m(m+1)/2}}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots (1-q^m)}
=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+q^m\right)}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> In order to prove (3) we follow a G.E. Andrews and prove a more general identity presented by him in *[The Theory of Partitions](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-1/issue-1/Review-George-E-Andrews-The-theory-of-partitions/bams/1183542336.full)*. This identity is due to Cauchy and stated as Theorem 2.1:
>
> **Theorem 2.1:** If $|q|<1, |t|<1$, then
> \begin{align*}
> 1+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-a)(1-aq)\cdots\left(1-aq^{m-1}\right)t^m}
> {(1-q)\left(1-q^2\right)\cdots\left(1-q^m\right)}
> =\prod_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-atq^m\right)}{\left(1-tq^m\right)}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

We start with the right-hand side of (4) and set
\begin{align*}
F(t)=\prod_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-atq^m\right)}{\left(1-tq^m\right)}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty A_mt^m\tag{5}
\end{align*}
Since the infinite product is uniformly convergent for fixed $a$ and $q$ inside $|t|<1$, the series representation of (5) is an analytic function inside $|t|<1$.

Now we consider
\begin{align*}
(1-t)F(t)&=(1-at)\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-atq^m\right)}{\left(1-tq^m\right)}\\
&=(1-at)\prod_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-atq^{m+1}\right)}{\left(1-tq^{m+1}\right)}\\
&=(1-at)F(tq)
\end{align*}
Comparing coefficients of $t^m$ in (5) we see
\begin{align*}
A_m-A_{m-1}=q^mA_m-aq^{m-1}A_{m-1}
\end{align*}
It follows by iteration:
\begin{align*}
A_m&=\frac{\left(1-aq^{m-1}\right)}{\left(1-q^m\right)}A_{m-1}\\
&=\frac{\left(1-aq^{m-1}\right)\left(1-aq^{m-2}\right)\cdots(1-a)}
{\left(1-q^m\right)\left(1-q^{m-1}\right)\cdots(1-q)}A_0
\end{align*}
and since $A_0=F(0)=1$ the claim (4) follows.
\begin{align*}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
\end{align*}

Replacing in (4) $a$ by $a/b$ and $t$ by $bz$ we obtain for $|bz|<1$
\begin{align*}
1+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(b-a)(b-aq)\cdots\left(b-aq^{m-1}\right)z^m}
{(1-q)\left(1-q^2\right)\cdots\left(1-q^m\right)}
=\prod_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-azq^m\right)}{\left(1-bzq^m\right)}
\end{align*}

> Setting $b=0, a=-1$ and $z=q$ we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{1+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{m(m+1)/2}}
> {(1-q)\left(1-q^2\right)\cdots\left(1-q^m\right)}}
> &=\prod_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(1+q^{m+1}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1+q^{m}\right)}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (3) and therefore also (1) follows.

Comment: It was answered in the comments, but I appreciate the effort went into this post!

Comment: @pSrIoGcNeAsLs: I think this nice identity deserves its own answer. Since you also gave $|q|<1$ I thought an analytic proof is more appropriate than a proof with formal power series. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A typical component of the RHS is

$$q^{a_1}q^{a_1+a_2}q^{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k}$$

where $a_i>0$ and consists of $k$ distinct parts.

This can be written as

$$q^{ka_1+(k-1)a_2+\cdots+a_k}$$

and then to

$$q^{ka_1}q^{(k-1)a_2}\cdots q^{a_k}$$

which is a typical component of the LHS.